# bitbucket: how to download latest tar.gz file of a bitbucket repo programmatically?

Tags: bitbucket

I have added a webhook in a bitbucket repo which sends updates about `push` events to a `node.js` server. How can I use that information to download the latest `tar.gz` file of the source code to my server ? When I visit the downloadpage of the repo, I can see a download button to download the latest zip of the branch. The link looks like this:

```
https://bitbucket.org/<account name>/<repo>/get/<some hash>.zip
```

I tried searching for the hash value in the webhook request that was received on the `node.js` server but could not find that.

I am also looking at the `bitbucket-api` npm module but cannot find a method to download the latest tarball.

Answer (score 0):

That hash is usually the 12 character prefix to the most recent commit id, but it can be any valid and unique branch/tag name or any unique commit id prefix.

You should have the the most recent commit id in the event payload: `push.changes.new.target.hash`. [[1]](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/event-payloads-740262817.html#EventPayloads-Push)